# pyspark selecting rows where column content length < x

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe where the contents of one column is of type string. I want to select only the rows in which the string length on that column is greater than 5. I have tried using the size function, but it only works on arrays.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, regexp_replace, size

new_df = df.select("col_1", explode(col("col_2")) \
    .select("col_1", "col_2") \
    .where(col("col_1").isNotNull()) \
    .where(size(col("col_2")) <= 5) \
    .distinct()
```

Is there any way I can select by column content length without using a UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695389/filtering-dataframe-using-the-length-of-a-column). You can use `length`.
So your example should look like:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, regexp_replace, length

new_df = df.select("col_1", explode(col("col_2")) \
    .select("col_1", "col_2") \
    .where(col("col_1").isNotNull()) \
    .where(length(col("col_2")) <= 5) \
    .distinct()
```